# Stretching width correctly to 100% of an inline-block element in IE6 and IE7

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer-7, css

I have the following markup, where I am attempting to get the right hand side of the second table to align with the right hand side of the heading above it. This works in IE8, Firefox and Chrome, but in IE6/7 the table is incorrectly stretched to fill the width of the page.

I'm using the [Trip Switch hasLayout trigger](http://www.brunildo.org/test/InlineBlockLayout.html) to apply `inline-block` in IE6/7.

**Does anyone know how (or even if) I can get the table only to fill the natural width of the wrapper element displayed with `inline-block` in IE6/7?**

You can see the code running live at http://jsbin.com/uyuva.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<style>
.wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
/* 
 display: inline-block triggers the wrapper element to have layout for IE 6/7.
 The trip switch then provides the inline component of the display behaviour.
 See http://www.brunildo.org/test/InlineBlockLayout.html for more details.
 */
.wrapper {
    *display: inline;
}

table {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>No width on table:</h1>
<div class="wrapper">
    <h2>The right hand side of the table doesn't stretch to the end of this heading</h2>
    <table><tr><td>foo</td></tr></table>
</div> text

<h1>Width on table:</h1>
<div class="wrapper">
    <h2>The right hand side of the table should stretch to the end of this heading</h2>
    <table style="width: 100%"><tr><td>foo</td></tr></table>
</div> text
</body>
</html>​
```

**Update**: here's another example of the problem, this time without using a table and using an absolutely positioned container element. You can see the code running live at http://jsbin.com/igila4.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<style>
div {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

input {
    width: 100%;
    *width: 95%; /* fudge factor for IE 6/7 which don't support box-sizing */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

textarea {
    width: 400px;
}
</style>
<body>
The width of the input and textarea below should be identical.<br/>
<div>
    <input value="This is an input with width 100%"><br/>
    <textarea>This is a text area with width 400px.</textarea>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the table to match specifically the H2's width above it or just fill the div.wrapper's width regardless of the H2?

Comment: I'm trying to get the table to match the H2's width if the H2 is wider than the natural width of the table. If the H2 is narrower than the natural table width then I expect the div.wrapper's width to end up as the natural table width.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't appear this can be achieved only through CSS.

I deliberately avoided using script because I much prefer to take advantage of the browser reflowing everything for me when the page is dynamically manipulated instead of having to write manual code to update the width.

In the end I side-stepped the issue by specifying a minimum width for my tables which should be wider than the length of any heading I'll have.

Internet Explorer 6 and 7 don't support `min-width` but as I've got common script that creates the tables I'm displaying I dynamically create an extra `thead` element that has a single cell that spans every column which I style to effectively give me the same result:

**CSS**

```
table {
    min-width: 600px;
}
th.min-width {
    *width: 600px;
}
```

**HTML table structure**

```
<table>
    <thead><tr><th colspan="3" class="min-width"></th></tr></thead>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>Column 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can set a width on the wrapper (e.g. 50em), then the table will expand to the width of the wrapper.

However, if you need the wrapper to be widthed dynamically, then you could use javascript to set the `width` of the table to the `offsetWidth` of the wrapper. Here's the page with the javascript added: http://jsbin.com/uyuva/5

I've only tested it on my IE 8 with compatibility mode running, since I don't have IE 6/7.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use javascript to get the width of the h2 and apply it to the table.  I don't believe that CSS can handle what you need in every browser *coughIEcough*

Here is a good [sample](http://www.cjboco.com/blog.cfm/post/determining-an-elements-width-and-height-using-javascript/) to reference